# How to fix error and correctly use Vuetify in Laravel/Vue application

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a problem. I installed Vuetify to my existing Laravel application (of course I had installed Vue before). My friend started to create templates with vuetify. Then we found an error in the console.

[image]
The error is:

> 'app' has been removed, use '' instead.

The application **works correctly** but we have this error. I think it is because we're using the application incorrectly. I was trying to include Vue components to blade template for a few ways but any were not well. I tried using `<v-app>`, `<app>` in blade, deleted `<v-app>` from App.vue and mixed different ways ineffectively.

This is part of my app.js:

```
const app = new Vue({  
   el:'#app',
   router,
   store,
   vuetify,
   render:h => h(App)
});
```

This is App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

This is blade template where I include vue component.

```
@extends('setup')
  @section('app')
     <div id="app">
        <App></App>
     </div>
  @endsection
```

How do I include the App component in my blade?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like a Vuetify versioning issue. In older versions of Vuetify you can create an app bar by using `<v-toolbar app></v-toolbar>`. Now the API has changed (starting with version 2.0+. If you just downloaded from npm I'm guessing you grabbed the latest version) - you have to use `<v-app-bar app></v-app-bar>` in place of adding the "app" prop to the toolbar. This is where the error is coming from.

As for how to include Vue and Vuetify correctly in your application, you *must* use the `v-app` tag when using Vuetify. And you *must* identify your Vue app with an id. The typical syntax is:

```html
<div id="app">
    <v-app>
        Your code here
    </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: the error really is leading you nowhere: [Vuetify] [BREAKING] 'app' has been removed, use '<v-app-bar app>' - normal people tend to replace <v-app> with <v-app-bar app>, what makes no sens at all..